# Can't dup NilClass (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to run my cucumber tests, but I get this error:

```
can't dup NilClass (TypeError)

/Users/jeffreyyong/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0-preview1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:40:in `dup'
```

What is the source of the problem and how I can go about debugging it?

Comment: do you happen to have `something.dup` in your codebase?

Comment: No, I think the "dup" is referring to the code belongs to the gems. But I don't really know what causes the problem.

Comment: I found the problem why, I was using ruby version 2.4.0-preview instead of ruby version 2.4.0.